# unable to reset safari user agent stylesheet whit custom css

Tags: css, wordpress, safari, css-reset

I cope with strange safari user agent stylesheet. Safari adds:

```
display: block;
-webkit-margin-before: 1em;
-webkit-margin-after: 1em;
-webkit-margin-start: 0px;
-webkit-margin-end: 0px;
```

which I can not overwrite even whit !important attribute i.e.

```
-webkit-margin-before: 0px !important;
```

Here is a screenshot of my problem
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqPku.png

Answer (score 0):

Set just

```
p {margin: 0;} /* or margin-top: 0; to reset just top margin */
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but I already tried it … and unfortunately it does not work either.

Comment: @SlaviTerziev: sorry, I can't help you better. You probably do somewhere a mistake (bad CSS selector). User agent styles are just the defaults one, nothing special. Do you see my CSS above in dev tools? If so, are they striked? If no, check the path to CSS file.